# MATLAB select variables from the workspace with a specific name

Tags: matlab

I would like to select all the variables in my workspace whos name follow a specific pattern. For example, I would like to compute the mean for all the variables in my workspace starting with the name `my_vars`.

I tried the following code:

> a = who('-regexp','my_vars*')
>
> result = mean(eval(a))

Howevever the `eval` function doesn't work for cells. Is there any work arround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`who` returned a cell array of char arrays (i.e. strings), with each element containing one variable name. You need to convert that to a string containing a comma-separated list of the names. Here's one way to do that:

```
my_vars1 = 1; my_vars2 = 2; my_vars3 = 3;
names = who('-regexp', 'my_vars*');
namelist = sprintf('%s,', names{:}); % sprintf reuses the format string if
                                     % there are more inputs than format specifiers 
namelist(end)=[];                    % strip last comma
eval(sprintf('mean([%s])', namelist))

ans =

     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works! However, I wish there was a simplier way to perform this.

Comment: @mat The simple way is to use vectors and matrices to store your data rather than discrete variables. `my_vars1`, `my_vars2`, `my_vars3` is much more cumbersome than `my_vars(1:3)`.